# Angular ng-bootstrap Modal Open Doesn't Support TemplateRef as Custom Component Passed from Template

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

Angular ng-bootstrap Modal open doesn't support `TemplateRef` as custom component passed from template.

Initially I was expecting to use Modal something like this:

```
this.modalService.open(ModalWindowComponent, {
    body: EmployeeFormComponent,
    title: 'Employee',
    data: {
        age: 28
    }
});
```

with `ModalWindowComponent` template like this:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{modal.title}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.close()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="modal.body">
            <!-- example: <app-employee-form></app-employee-form> -->
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

But then I realized it's impossible, or requires super complex logic with dynamic components creation. So, I decided to use recommended template-driven approach, having modal template in component template. But since I need custom body, I created `ModalWindowComponent` with this template:

```
<ng-template>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="ref.dismiss()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="ref.close()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I was expecting to use it this way:

**template**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="open(modal)">Open</button>
<app-modal-window [ref]="modal" [title]="'Title'" #modal>
    Body
</app-modal-window>
```

**component**

```
open(modal: NgbModalRef): void {
    this.modalService.open(modal).result.then((result: any) => {
        this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason: any) => {
        this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
}
```

But I see this error: *No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?* I tried to fix it by adding `ModalWindowComponent` to `entryComponents` of related module, but it didn't help.

However, this works:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="open(modal)">Open</button>
<ng-template #modal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Body
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

So, the question is what am I doing wrong? Maybe there's a better way to achieve the desired behavior? I understand that Modal doesn't support class-driven custom body component, but seems like I can't get template-driven to work as well.

**Demo:** https://angular-v6amvy.stackblitz.io

**Package versions:**

Angular: 6.0.0

ng-bootstrap: 2.1.2

Bootstrap: 4.1.1

**P.S.** I also took a look at https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals and https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview, but seems like they don't support needed behavior as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the devil is in the details again.

`ModalWindowComponent` should be like this:

**component**

```
export class ModalWindowComponent {  
    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() close;
    @Input() dismiss;
}
```

**template**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="dismiss()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="close()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Usage should be like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="open(modal)">Open</button>
<ng-template #modal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <app-modal-window [title]="'Title'" [close]="c" [dismiss]="d">
        Body
    </app-modal-window>
</ng-template>
```

**Demo:** https://angular-v6amvy-pttrng.stackblitz.io

Comment: Any suggestion how are you loading the `EmployeeFormComponent` or any other component dynamically in `ng-content` under the modal body?

Comment: Here is my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66434541/load-angular-component-dynamically-in-bootstrap-modal