# Load angular component dynamically in bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to make a reusable `quickView` modal in my app to load any component dynamically using the [ng-bootstrap modal library](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

It's working fine as far I am loading the same example component as shown in docs, but not for the components I created to test.

How can I use the `quickView` modal for dynamic components creation to load in `modal-body`?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quickview

I am using simple if/else to open a component in the modal based on name `string`.

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary mr-2" (click)="open('default')">Launch default</button>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-danger mr-2" (click)="open('red')">Launch red</button>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open('blue')">Launch blue</button>
```

```
open(name: string) {
    if (name === "default") {
      const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
      modalRef.componentInstance.name = "Default";
    } else if (name === "red") {
      const modalRef = this.modalService.open(RedComponent);
      modalRef.componentInstance.name = "Red";
    } else if (name === "blue") {
      const modalRef = this.modalService.open(BlueComponent);
      modalRef.componentInstance.name = "Blue";
    }
  }
```

I also tried with componentFactoryResolver to inject my component into `modal-body` but that also throw error `Error: Cannot read property 'viewContainerRef' of undefined`

```
 <div class="modal-body">
      <ng-template quickView></ng-template>
 </div>
```

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
        RedComponent
      );
      const viewContainerRef = this.quickView.viewContainerRef;
      viewContainerRef.clear();

      const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<any>(
        componentFactory
      );
      componentRef.instance.name = "Red";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try adding modal service so it can resolveComponentFactory custom components and in that case the modal will be singleton.

**modal.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, ComponentFactoryResolver } from "@angular/core";
import { NgbModal } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
@Injectable()
export class ModalService {
  constructor(
    private ngbModal: NgbModal,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

  showDefaultModalComponent(theComponent: any, name: any) {
    const componenetFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      theComponent
    );
    const modalRef = this.ngbModal.open(theComponent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = name;
    return modalRef;
  }

  showFeaturedDialog(theComponent: any, name: any) {
    const componenetFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      theComponent
    );

    const modalRef = this.ngbModal.open(theComponent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = name;
    return modalRef;
  }
}
```

And then inject that service into the main component.

```
export class NgbdModalComponent {
  constructor(private customModal: ModalService) {}

  open(name: string) {
    if (name === "default") {
      this.customModal.showDefaultModalComponent(NgbdModalContent, "Default");
    } else if (name === "red") {
      this.customModal.showFeaturedDialog(RedComponent, "Red");
    } else if (name === "blue") {
      this.customModal.showFeaturedDialog(BlueComponent, "Blue");
    }
  }
}
```

In case you want to use quickView directive please check that the reason why your example is not working is in RedComponent and BlueComponent. **You have added twice @Component decorator** as seen on the example bellow:

[image]

Please see the edited and working Stackblitz example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quickview-ykwz4i?file=src/app/modal-component.ts

*Note: Entry components in Angular 11 are deprecitated.*

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, this made my day! Can I also add header, close button somehow in the dynamic `showFeaturedDialog` method to display header by default instead adding that in each component HTML?

Comment: Sadly ngbmodal doesn't support ng-content / content projection. There are some other ways to do that but you may get into complicating the code.

Comment: make sure to include ->providers: [ModalService, NgbActiveModal, NgbModal]

Comment: Do you have idea how to implement this, if instead of `Component` the source of `NgbModal` is `TemplateRef`?

Answer (score -1):

You can inject the components dynamically in modal by declaring those components in entryComponents in your app module as follows.

```
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        RedComponent,
        BlueComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    entryComponents: [RedComponent, BlueComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: That doesn't work when I want to dynamically load different components into same modal https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quickview